# Is it common to use "work environment" and "work circumstance" to refer to relationship?

Tags: vocabulary

When I say something "My colleagues and I have a harmonious relationship. We are willing to help each other all the time", I am describing my "work environment", "work circumstance" or something else?

Comment: Which word do you think would be most appropriate, and why? Please edit your question to provide this information. Maybe look in a dictionary too, and quote references.

Comment: Neither of those phrases commonly mean anything about personal relationships. They certainly don't indicate that anything is necessarily harmonious.

Comment: You are describing your working relationships.